# Making the JVM lightweight using Docker and Azure Kubernetes Service

Tags: java, node.js, spring-boot, jvm, microservices

I'm having a bit of an issue.  I'm building a Java Spring application, but when I try to run it on Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Docker, it appears to be using a lot of system resources (RAM, CPU are the main considerations).  Aside from Spring itself, the code is fairly lightweight, so I don't understand why it is using so much system resources.  Is there any best practices I should be aware of to reduce the system resource footprint of my Java Spring application?

The purpose of the application is as a lightweight CRUD service on top of a MongoDB database.  The DB interaction layer uses Spring Data or Morphia for direct DB operations (older applications are using Morphia, newer development uses Spring Data, with QueryDSL in some places as appropriate).

In particular, the metric I am comparing to is NodeJS, so I would like to make my Java application run at a level comparable to a Node application of similar size/scope.

Thanks!

Dockerfile (some params redacted):

```
FROM openjdk:8-jre-alpine

RUN mkdir /[redacted]
ADD *.jar /[redacted]

ENV JVM_OPTS="-Xmx256M"
ENV JVM_ARGS="-Dspring.profiles.active=[redacted]"

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "sh", "-c", "java $JVM_ARGS $JVM_OPTS -jar /[redacted]" ]
```

The only thing the Spring profile parameter does is set a bunch of configuration which is needed for the business logic of the application.  It doesn't set anything JVM-wise.

Comment: What resources, RAM, CPU, IOps? What type of workflow, CPU intensive calculations or network request routing? Do note that JVM warmus up over time by JITing the code, it doesn't have all the optimizations from the very startup.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Added some additional contextual information.  Does that help to clarify?

Comment: Sorry but it's too vague, you need to dig into the setup and see where the time is spent in each case. NodeJS service might be doing no payload serialization when dealing with MongoDB. Understand where the time is spent by Java service and compare it with NodeJS service.

Comment: @KarolDowbecki Sorry, I'm not experienced in benchmarking.  Can you provide some tips as to how to get that information?  Does Java provide it as standard logging or so I have to work to get it?

Comment: My colleague (actually my boss) did some research and claimed to have found (not sure how trustworthy he is) that the additional resource usage is coming from the JVM itself, not from the code.  He has therefore instructed not to use any JVM-based technologies (except Scala, for some reason...); I'd like to show him that the technology is not the problem, but rather we should improve the implementation.

Comment: @Ertai87, share your dockerfile here bro. Give us some points to review

Comment: @AllanChua Added!  Sorry, I don't know what information is useful, so if you need something, please let me know!